# UART0 to UART2 gateway (sort of) for AtMega2560

Tags: interrupt, avr

I connected a device to the UART0 of the AtMega2560. I want to transfer the UART0 data to the UART2 to view it on the Terminal(PC).

When I connect the device directly to the PC using an UART to serial device (FTDI) It sends the data nicely.

When I put the UART2 in the middle for said purpose, then It only sends the first line, specifically:

`Ver V2DAPV142 On-Line:` And then forgets. Sometimes it doesn't send the first line too.

Code:

```
#define UART0_BUFFER_SIZE 40 
#define RX_WAIT 65000 
volatile unsigned char UART0_rx_ArrUC85[UART0_BUFFER_SIZE]; 
volatile  unsigned char UART0_rx_ArrLength = 0, UART0_rx_ArrIndex = 0; 

void uart0_init( unsigned int baudrate ) 
{ 

    UBRR0H = (unsigned char) (baudrate>>8); 
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char) baudrate; 

    UCSR0B = ( 1 << RXEN0 ) | ( 1 << TXEN0 ) | (1<<RXCIE0); 
    UCSR0C = ( 1 << USBS0 ) | ( 1 << UCSZ01 ) | ( 1 << UCSZ00 );  // 8N1 

} 

void USART2Init(UINT16 ubrr_value) 
{ 
   UBRR2L = ubrr_value; 
   UBRR2H = (ubrr_value>>8); 

   UCSR2C|=(3<<UCSZ20); 

   UCSR2B = (1<<RXEN2) | (1<<TXEN2);  

} 
ISR(USART0_RX_vect) 
{ 
   unsigned char recChar = UDR0; 
   if (UART0_BUFFER_SIZE > UART0_rx_ArrLength) 
   {    
      UART0_rx_ArrUC85[UART0_rx_ArrIndex++] = recChar; 
      UART0_rx_ArrLength = UART0_rx_ArrIndex; 
   } 

} 

void uart2_putchar(UINT8 data) 
{ 
    //Local variables 
    unsigned int i; 
    for( i = 0; !( UCSR2A & ( 1 << UDRE2 ) ); i++ ) // Wait for empty transmit buffer 
    { 
        if( i > RX_WAIT )                           // How long one should wait 
        { 
            return ;                              // Give feedback to function caller 
        } 
    } 
    UDR2 = data;                                    // Start transmitting     
    //return (int)data;                               // Cast and return int value 
} 


void uart2_puts(unsigned char *str) 
{ 
   UINT8 dat; 
   for( ;*str != '\0'; ) 
   { 
      dat= *str++ ; 
      uart2_putchar(dat); 
   } 

} 
int main() 
{ 
   USART2Init(8); 
   uart0_init(103); 
   sei(); 
   while(1) 
   {       
      if(UART0_rx_ArrLength>0) 
      { 
         uart2_puts((unsigned char *) UART0_rx_ArrUC85);       
         UART0_rx_ArrLength = UART0_rx_ArrIndex = 0;                      
      } 
   } 
}
```

What could be the issue. 
I checked it with same and different baud rates too for UART0 and UART2.

Comment: did you tried both uarts and they work correctly? You should connect the uart0 to pc and try it with the hiperterminal (for example), then do the same with uart2. Please, tell us if both works.

Comment: The issue was not at all software .. it was ckt power level issue. When it gets hot it doesn't send data on UART#. Now it works. Took 2 days to figure it out. My work pressure hasn't allowed me to update it here. :| Thanks for responding anyways .. I am currently figuring 'Magnetometer Issue' Out. Please refer: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21007/magnetometer-dynamic-calibration/21249#21249

Comment: Great then! I think maybe you can answer the question so other people know that it was resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was circuitry power level. The power supply was not sufficient for the Pen-Drive ctrlr and the regulator was not able to source for its communication power level. Hence it was not working sometimes. Further we have tested it and drew a conclusion that after giving sufficient power to the Pen-Drive ctrlr using another power regulator, the above said communication takes nicely place. I hope this can help ppl to draw attention towards the possible circuitry issues.